# Can I use fabric as a lib in a concurrent way?

Tags: python, fabric

I am planning to write a remote agent module as bellow:

```
from fabric.api import run as fab_run
from fabric.api import env as fab_env


class RemoteAgent(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port, user, password):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    def set_env(self):
        fab_env.host_string = "%s:%s" % (self.host, self.port)
        fab_env.user = self.user
        fab_env.password = self.password

    def run(self, cmd):
        self.set_env()
        return fab_run(cmd)
```

So I can use `RemoteAgent` like this:

```
ra = RemoteAgent('192.168.1.102', 22, 'worker', 'password')
ra.run('killall java')
```

But `RemoteAgent` can not be used concurrently, or there will be a race condition.

My question is: how can use fabric as a lib in a concurrent way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on type of concurrency you would like to use.

It's not a good idea to use fabric with thread concurrency. Fabric is not thread safe (see last question in [FAQ](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html)).

There is no problem though using process concurrency with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Fabric uses it internally to provide their [Parallel execution](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/parallel.html) functionality.

Comment: Yes, I am reading the fabric source code and trying to update it for thread concurrency. Ah, let me use multiprocessing to finish my job first:)

Comment: Please not that as of version 2 Fabric *is* thread-safe (https://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html)

Answer (score -1):

There is a parallel decorator in fabric.api, [parallel in fabric](https://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.0/usage/parallel.html)

Comment: It's using fabric as a tool not a lib.